# Entropy-like quantity

Tags: reference-request, shannon-entropy

For $p\in[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\alpha\ge1$, define
$$ H_\alpha(p) = \sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}p_i|\log(p_i)|^\alpha.
$$
When $\sum_i p_i=1$ and $\alpha=1$, $H_1(p)$ is just the Shannon entropy of the distribution $p$. Has anyone encountered the object $H_\alpha$ anywhere in the literature? A reference would be much appreciated. I'm thinking of calling $H_\alpha$ *hyperentropy* for $\alpha>1$; is *that* term already taken by chance?

Comment: Not an answer, but linking https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3781318/name-of-a-quantity-related-to-the-shannon-entropy

Comment: Thanks!! I'm curious about the *other* guy's motivation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the $\alpha^{\mathrm{th}}$ moment of the Tribus [surprisal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_content#cite_note-Tribus1961-6).

This generalizes the statement that *entropy = expected surprisal*.

Or in [Ross's textbook](http://julio.staff.ipb.ac.id/files/2015/02/Ross_8th_ed_English.pdf), "expected surprise".

Comment: So... "moment of surprise"?

Comment: I searched Ross's book for "expected surprise" and nothing came up -- what page is it on?

Comment: Any chance you have Trubus's book in pdf?

Comment: You can search for "surprise"

Answer (score 1):

So we ended up calling this quantity *the $\alpha$th moment of information* and proving some inequalities about it:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.12680
(paper to appear in the NIPS 2021 conference).